# How to enable auto update for Chrome apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, auto-update, google-chrome-app

I've written a packaged app for Chrome and I want it to update automatically for every user which have already installed the app.

I've uploaded new updated zip but there nothing was updated in my tester accounts so I had to delete and install the app again.

How to set update option on auto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in Chrome is auto-updated. It might take up to a couple of days for the rollout to hit all of the installs.